# Is there a way of storing posts and pages under the same hierarchy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm working on a site which needs to have pages and posts sorted into the same categories. The pages have their own individual hierarchy structure.

Is there a way to do this using a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a custom taxonomy is the best way to achieve this.

For a cat breeder site I’ve set a taxonomy for colors (in german: Farbe):

```
register_taxonomy(
    'farbe',
    array( 'post', 'page' ),
    array(
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'label'         => 'Farbe (Fell)',
        'query_var'     => 'farbe',
        'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'farbe')
    )
);
```

Note the third parameter `array( 'post', 'page' )`.

Now you can find all posts and page covering the color **black** at [/farbe/black/](http://ig-bkh.de/farbe/black/).

That’s all, WP will do the rest for you. :)

**Update**

WordPress will search for a [matching template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display).

To link to this taxonomy, add the following code to the meta data box (tags, categories, date etc.) of your posts:

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'farbe', ' · Farbe: ', ', ', '' );
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://example.com/farbe/black/" rel="tag">black</a>
```

Screenshot for taxonomy “Farbe” in the post edit screen:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to differentiate between the post type in the query as well, like /farbe/black/post ?

Comment: Not per default. You could try to hook into such a request and sort it out with a custom query … but would you want to do that?

Comment: no, not for this example.

Comment: Sorry, I lost a ›why‹. :) **Why** would you want to do that? The difference between posts and pages is an internal; the user should never care about such things imho.

Comment: Because pages are being used for content which doesn't change regularly but the users want the page content to also appear on the area of the site which displays news i.e. normal blog posts. I'm just trying to figure out the best way to organise the content of a site I have inherited.

Comment: toscho - presumably in your example you add a new category called 'black' by clicking 'Farbe' in the admin interface? Also, what template would WP try to use by default?

Comment: codecowboy, I have updated my answer. Your regular posts are still available separately.